# How to launch an external process in C#, using a cmd window

Tags: c#, .net

I am having trouble executing an external console application using Process.Start

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "dump";
p.StartInfo.FileName = "test.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = s;
p.Start();
```

When the argument that p generates executes, the external application crashes, although if I copy the exact same argument in a command line window it runs fine.

So my question instead how would I create a new instance of a command window and then add the command test.exe + s to run?

So effectively I am launching cmd and then adding my arguments on to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
ProcessStartInfo processToRunInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();    
processToRunInfo.Arguments = "Arguments");
processToRunInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
processToRunInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\yourDir\\";
processToRunInfo.FileName = "test.exe";
//processToRunInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
//processToRunInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = processToRunInfo;
process.Start();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run `test.exe prm1 prm2` via cmd, use `cmd.exe /c test.exe prm1 prm2`. Though I don't really understand what this has to do with the crashes. Sounds like your problem is with `test.exe` - find out what's causing it to crash, and that will help you fix your C# code so that you don't need the `cmd`.

One of the places I would examine is the working directory. When you set it to "dump", are you sure the current directory is what you expect? Try using a full path first. It's possible that `test.exe` happens to be in the system path so it gets executed, but its working directory is not what it expects, and this causes it to crash.

Answer (score 1):

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "/full/path/to/dump";
p.StartInfo.FileName = "/full/path/to/test.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = s; // will call 'text.exe s'
p.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments.aspx#Y400).

You need to Create an instance of the StartInfo class and user Start()  such as

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("IExplore.exe");
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
Process.Start(startInfo);
startInfo.Arguments = "www.example.com";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Try it!

Rewriting your code would look something like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("test.exe");
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = "dump";
startInfo.Arguments = "s";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```